# Horner's rule and direct method in python

Tags: python, numerical-methods

I am trying to solve the following question. I have made codes for implanting the direct method and Horner's rule, which I believe I have done this correctly. However past that I am having some problems figuring out the rest. Looking for some help with this, all help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Here is the code I have produced for Horner's rule, which I believe I have done correctly.

```
def poly_horner(A, x):
    p = A[-1]
    i = len(A) - 2
    while i >= 0:
        p = p * x + A[i]
        i -= 1
   return p
```

And here is the code I have produced for the direct method:

```
def poly_naive(A, x):
    p = 0
    for i, a in enumerate(A):
        p += (x ** i) * a
   return p
```

How can I put this code together and finish the rest?

Comment: _How can I put this code together and finish the rest?_ Do you mean you would like to know how to implement the `flops` thing?

Comment: @AGNGazer yes, I am looking for any help that can get me started on solving this question

Comment: You mustn't implement the direct method with the operator **, only with multiples.

Comment: @user123: sorry, no, your job.

Comment: thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `global` as suggested in the paper,

```
flops = 0
def add(x1, x2):
    global flops
    flops += 1
    return x1 + x2

def multiply(x1, x2):
    global flops
    flops += 1
    return x1 * x2

def poly_horner(A, x):
    global flops
    flops = 0
    p = A[-1]
    i = len(A) - 2
    while i >= 0:
        p = add(multiply(p, x), A[i])
        i -= 1
    return p

def poly_naive(A, x):
    global flops
    flops = 0
    p = 0
    for i, a in enumerate(A):
        xp = a
        for _ in range(i):
            xp = multiply(xp, x)
        p = add(p, xp)
    return p
```

To run the above code, for example:

```
>>> poly_horner([1,2,3,4,5], 2)
129
>>> print(flops)
8
```

Compare to `numpy`'s `polyval`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.polyval([5,4,3,2,1], 2)
129
```